# Reference request on pseudo-determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, determinant

I am looking for a reference on pseudo-determinants$^{(1)}$. I am mostly interested on general and/or basic equalities and properties such as those obtained for [determinants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant). Any pointers would be appreciated.

$^{(1)}$ **Definition.** The pseudo-determinant of a square matrix $A$ is defined as the product of the nonzero eigenvalues of $A$.